# Multiple git users on the same instance using bash script

Tags: bash, git, github, gitlab

Hello i am trying to create a script that will enable everyone who logs into company PC to be able to commit changes to a gitlab/github repository with his own company username.
I was able to create a script who will generate ssh key and grab the username + mail,
but i am not sure it is good enough for my situation.
Can you please advice for an approach?

```
    #!/bin/bash

if [[ -f  ${XXX_HOME}/.ssh/id_$SUDO_USER  ]]
then
         echo "DEBUG:There is a SSH key generated for that account, skiping step."

else
         ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f $XXX_HOME/.ssh/id_$SUDO_USER -C "$SUDO_USER@XXX.com" -q -P ""
fi

export GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS="'user.email=${SUDO_USER}@XXX.com' 'user.name=${SUDO_USER}'"
export GIT_SSH_KEY_NAME=id_${SUDO_USER}
```

Comment: A common way to do this is to have keys provided by an LDAP server and/or use roaming profiles. In either case, the public key needs to be registered with the server, which has to be done by the user (or an admin). GitLab allows you to fetch public keys for users automatically from LDAP, not sure about GitHub.